# Float right span on the same line in summary tag without div clear both breaking to the next line

Tags: html, css

I would like there to be one line of text with "ABC" on left and "DEF" on right on the same level as marker of summary tag. However, if I use clear on both `<div>` elements it breaks to the next line. Without the last `<div>` it is about perfect except the "DEF" part is a bit higher than the rest line.

How can I fix this?

```html
<div class="whatever">
   <details>
      <summary>
         <div style="display:inline">
            <span style="float:left">ABC</span>
            <span style="float:right">DEF</span>
         </div>
      </summary>
   </details>
</div>
```

Comment: make abc float left , else float goes under previous non floatting element before going to right or left . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float (computed value shows floatting element tun into a block level element)

Comment: Ive done it earlier and the result is actually left and right parts on the same line, but details marker is broken, its position probably after "ABC" at the lower corner. So weird

Comment: Could you clarity your question? Do you want to put text inside the div and with the text appearing in the same line as ABC and DEF or something else?

Comment: maybe it helps to realize issue https://imgur.com/a/tTYnvIb

Comment: It seems that it is not reproducible in the snippet your provided?

Comment: simpy want to make two spans in summary tag at the same line, one is float:left, opposite is float:right

Comment: @LearningMathematics Clearly it is and i have no idea why this is so

Comment: @IriaMihairowa umm... That would be a difficult situation to deal with cuz we can't really know what the issue is. Could you somehow make your site accessible to us? Or include some more relevant code constituting a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Ok, the next clue is Vue js, If I put the snippet to index.html body I catch a glimpse of right case, but then App.vue intercepts the site display and there are the issue at absolutely the same code

Comment: This could represent the problem, further need to place "ABC" after markup of details tag: <details>
    <summary>
        <span style="float:left">ABC</span>
        <span style="float:right">DEF</span>
    </summary>
</details>

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on but according to the comments I think the issue is with height of `<span>DEF</span>` a little off with respect to `<span>ABC</span>`, if not please correct me in comments. Have you tried without using float ?. The thing is I was not able to position the `::marker` after `<summary>` but I think it can be done in your codebase. Here is what I did to place ABC and DEF to extreme ends.

```
<summary>
  <div style="position: relative;text-align: right; /* display:inline is removed*/">
    <span style="display: inline-block;position: absolute; left:0; /* float:left; is removed*/">ABC</span> 
    <span style="display: inline-block; /* float:right; is removed*/">DEF</span>
  </div>
</summary>
```